# Next number in the sequence

Tags: number-sequence, letter-sequence

Can you find the number that should be placed instead of the xxxx?

> `0000A...`
>   `0111AB..`
>   `2012BB..`
>   `3103AB..`
>   `4140AAA.`
>   `4150AABB`
>   `xxxxAAAA`

Good luck!

Comment: Is the punctuation meaningful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next term is:

> 5140AAAA

The terms in the sequence are:

> A series of guesses in the game Mastermind. The number is the guess, the letters indicate how close the guess is to the hidden sequence: A represents a correct number in the correct position, B represents a correct number but not in the correct position. Since the letters for the last guess are AAAA, the last guess must be the hidden sequence.